# Is it a good practise to assign null to a java CDI/EJB bean reference if you are over with it?

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection, ejb, cdi

Does that makes any sense - to show JVM/CDI container that I want to release SomeOtherBean?

```
@Singleton
public class SingleBean {

   @Inject
   SomeOtherBean someBean;

   private Map values;

   @PostSonstruct
   private void postConstruct() {
      someBean.doThis();
      someBean.doThat();
      values = someBean.retrieveValues();
      //...
      someBean = null; //don't need this anymore.
    }

   public Object getValue(String key) {
      return values.get(key);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use @Inject on constructor of SingleBean itself and don't store the value of someotherbean in a field if you don't need it any more.

Answer (score 2):

The CDI system will almost certainly still have the bean in its registry, so you won't be releasing any memory. A better approach, though, is to use constructor injection instead of `@PostConstruct` whenever practical, as it's simpler and easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

That assignment to `null` is not necessary, since the `SomeOtherBean` instance would still be referenced from the DI framework. Besides, it's known that the garbage collector frees up memory undeterministically.

As others suggest, you'd better inject the bean in the constructor and fill the map there, instead of doing it in the `@PostConstruct` method.

**EDIT** (as per @JanGalinski's comment):

Regarding the "good practice" part of the question, I don't believe it's good practice to leave a `null` reference in a field. What if someone later extends the `SingleBean` class and expects that field to have a non-null reference to `SomeOtherBean`? You might end up with a NPE...

Comment: Well, it does has an effect: the field injection defines an api: "if you create an instance, you will need SomeOtherbean". If my task would be to extend that Bean, I would assume a non-null value and fail with an NPE ... so the effect is unnecessary confusion.